# Would men include boys in the New Testament?

Tags: acts, baptism

> "Now there were Jews living in Jerusalem, devout men from every nation
>   under heaven"
>   - Acts 2:5, NASB

Men translates Aner (Strong G435) which means Male according to Greek lexicons.

> "So then, those who had received his word were baptized; and that day
>   there were added about three thousand souls."
>   - Acts 2:41 NASB

Also, it seems that the 3,000 souls were a subset of the devout men from every nation.

Would the 3,000 baptized men (male) include boys (male children) as well or they would have been grown up men (adults) only?

Answer (score 1):

**Would men include boys in the New Testament?**

> "Now there were Jews living in Jerusalem, devout men from every nation
> under heaven" - Acts 2:5, NASB

Men translates Aner (Strong G435) which means Male according to Greek lexicons.

> "So then, those who had received his word were baptized; and that day
> there were added about three thousand souls." - Acts 2:41 NASB

The Bible was written in a world, then dominated by men, women however should not be excluded , the NET and other translations  render  Acts 2:5 as follows: "Now there were devout Jews from every nation under heaven residing in Jerusalem."   The NASB is a literal translation.

The answer to your question is to be found in the verse  you   quoted: "those who had received his word were baptized." Young children  are not able to "received his word,"hence  are not capable of grasping   the basic  commandments  of God's Word and thus  dedicate themselves. **The answer  is -No .Therefore the question that arises is.**

**Should babies, young boys and girls be baptized?**

To help understand baptism, we will  look into  the scriptures at some examples of baptism,   the baptism of Apollos, a zealous man, the Ethiopian eunuch a devout Jewish proselyte, and Cornelius the first gentile to be baptized.

**Apollos was well versed in the scriptures.**

Apollos was a Jewish Christian  well versed in the scriptures, when in Corinth Paul met him  and some disciples  who were only baptized in the baptism of  John, when they heard about Jesus, they were baptized again in the name of the Lord Jesus.( Acts 19:1-7 NASB)

**The Ethiopian Eunuch, Philip preached to him.**

The Ethiopian eunuch was  devout Jewish proselyte, who had a good knowledge of the  Hebrew Scriptures, after Philip explained  to him  the fulfillment of the scriptures in Christ, accepted it, and then asked  to be baptized.

Acts 8:34-37  (NASB)

> 34 "!The eunuch answered Philip and said, “Please tell me, of whom
> does the prophet say this? Of himself or of someone else?” 35 Then
> Philip opened his mouth, and beginning from this Scripture he preached
> Jesus to him. 36 As they went along the road they came to some water;
> and the eunuch *said, “Look! Water! What prevents me from being
> baptized?” 37 And Philip said, “If you believe with all your heart,
> you may.” And he answered and said, “I believe that Jesus Christ is
> the Son of God.”

**Cornelius , was a devout, God fearing man.**

" He was a devout, God-fearing man, as was all his household; he did many acts of charity for the people and prayed to God regularly.(Acts 10:2 NET)

Recommend reading Acts chapter 10

Peter explained to Cornelius that  : " in every nation the person who fears him and does what is right is welcomed before him." (Acts 10:35 NASB) and that everyone that exercises faith in Jesus receives forgiveness of his sins : " About him all the prophets testify, that everyone who believes in him receives forgiveness of sins  through his name.”(Acts 10:43)

The three thousand that  were baptized, were  devout Jews and proselytes from all nations , mature people that evidently had excellent knowledge of the Hebrew Scriptures and were thus able to understand  the will of God and so took the decision to get baptized.  Apollos and the Ethiopian eunuch  were  also devout Jewish proselytes , Cornelius feared God and  exercise faith in Jesus.

Baptism for all must be in harmony with the scriptures ,otherwise it is not acceptable to God,

**Faith from hearing.**

Paul says that faith comes from hearing-children do not understand let alone have faith

Romans 10:16-17 (NASB)

> 16 "However, they did not all heed the good news; for Isaiah says,
> “Lord, who has believed our report?” 17 So faith comes from hearing,
> and hearing by the word of Christ."

**Preached to and understand the gospel.**

Jesus said to his disciples :“Go into all the world and preach the gospel to all creation-babies and children cannot be preached to.

Mark 16:15-17  (NASB)

> 15 "And He said to them, “Go into all the world and preach the gospel
> to all creation. 16 He who has believed and has been baptized shall be
> saved; but he who has disbelieved shall be condemned. 17 These  signs
> will accompany those who have believed: in My name they will cast out
> demons, they will speak with new tongues."

**Taught by God.**

Jesus said that no one come to me unless taught by God. Children cannot be taught  by God.

John 6:44-45 (NASB)

> 44 "No one can come to Me unless the Father who sent Me draws him; and
> I will raise him up on the last day. 45 It is written in the prophets,
> ‘And they shall all be taught of God.’ Everyone who has heard and
> learned from the Father, comes to Me."

**Repent and then be baptized  for the forgiveness of sins.**

Children should not  be baptized , until  they are not  old enough to understand  repentance as required by God in his Word the  "Bible" ,and choose to do so of their own free will.

Acts 2:38  (NASB)

> 38 "Peter said to them, “Repent, and each of you be baptized in the
> name of Jesus Christ for the forgiveness of your sins; and you will
> receive the gift of the Holy Spirit."

**It is an individual decision.**

To be baptized is an individual  commitment that a person makes when he/she repents and then gets baptized .  The Ethiopian eunuch said to Philip:“I believe that Jesus Christ is the Son of God.” This is and individual choice that a child cannot make make.

Acts 8:37 (NASB)

37 And Philip said, “If you believe with all your heart, you may.” And he answered and said, “I believe that Jesus Christ is the Son of God.”

**Conclusion:**

In view of the above that ," faith comes from hearing," "must be preached to and understand the gospel," and "repentance for the forgiveness of sins," such things infants and young children cannot do . I personally believe that most children are mature enough to make this commitment at the age of about fourteen.

Therefore , Christian baptism requires for all people, young and old  to know  and understand the basic requirements of God's Word  at the time of their  baptism, and so are able to  obey them after baptism. God wants people to worship him in  a way that is acceptable to him, love him  and  do his will , as Jesus did,

**Notes.**

**Some believe that children are lost if they are not baptized**, is this so? Paul wrote that the unbelieving member  is holy and so are the children by virtue of the merit of the  believing   Christian member of the family, husband or wife. That is another reason why baby baptism is not necessary. If the child dies before is old enough to  make dedication to God,believing  parents are assured by Paul's words that their child is holy and  will be resurrected from the dead.

1 Corinthians 7:14  (ESV)

> 14 "For the unbelieving husband is made holy because of his wife, and
> the unbelieving wife is made holy because of her husband. Otherwise
> your children would be unclean, but as it is, they are holy."
>
> 28 "Do not marvel at this; for an hour is coming, in which all who are
> in the tombs will hear His voice, 29 and will come forth; those who
> did the good deeds to a resurrection of life, those who committed the
> evil deeds to a resurrection of judgment."

Answer (score 0):

To be perfectly honest I don't know how one would know the answer to your question? All we can do is "speculate?" I do know from Acts 5:14, "And all the more believers in the Lord, multitudes of men and women, were constantly added to their number."

Just look at the next two verses,vs15, "to such an extent that they even carried the sick out into the streets, and laid them on cots and pallents, so that when Peter came by, at least his shadow might fall on any one of them." Vs16, "And also the people from the cities in the vicinity of Jersalem were coming together bringing people who were sick or afflicted with unclean spirits; and they were all being healed."

I think there would be a good chance that young men/women and children were in this group of people. Bottom line, anything is possible as to your question but it just boils down to speculation. Why the question truthseeker?

Comment: Because it seems that baptism candidates in the NT were adults only. Just wanted to find evidences for this.